# UserControl not sending Dependency Property Changes to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom tree view user control, that I wanted to expose a couple bindable properties my main window.

In my tree view user control code behind I did this.

**TreeViewControl.xaml.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFolderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFolder", typeof (Folder), typeof (TreeViewControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFolderChanged));


    public Folder SelectedFolder
    {
        get { return (Folder)GetValue(SelectedFolderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedFolderProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnFolderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //just wanted to test if we get here, which we do everytime
        MessageBox.Show("WeChanged");
    }

    private void TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var folderViewModel = e.NewValue as FolderViewModel;

        if (folderViewModel != null)
        {
            //this is where we change the dependency property value
            SelectedFolder = folderViewModel.Folder;
        }
    }
```

I don't really care about setting values through this property, just reading them.  I know a read only property should be used here, but at this point i'm just trying to get anything working.

I bind it in my main window like this

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<controls:TreeViewControl SelectedFolder={Binding MySelectedFolder, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

Then in my main view model

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
private Folder _mySelectedFolder;
public Folder MySelectedFolder 
{
    get {return _mySelectedFolder;}
    set {this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _mySelectedFolder, value); }
}

//constructor
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
     //just listen for changes
     this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.MySelectedFolder).Subscribe(x => {
          //this will never get hit, and MySelectedFolder is always null
          MessageBox.Show("The selection was changed");
      });
}
```

If it matters i'm just binding the main window to the view model like this

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

So the problem is the main window never knows about any SelectedFolder changes, and I would like it to.  Currently I have no idea what to try next to get these changes working.  I have no clue what's wrong.

If it wasn't obvious, I'm using ReactiveUI here, but I don't think that has anything to do with my problems.  I think it's more of a lack of understanding of how dependency properties are suppose to work.

Does anyone have any hints of to why this isn't working?  Or why in the code behind the changes are recognized, but they aren't pushed back out to my main window?

**Edit**
I noticed when I do set the property through the binding, the update will trigger in the user control, but still cannot figure out why the changes won't come the other way.

Comment: Hope you can find the answer, indeed it's too strange I think. Remember to add the answer yourself and notify me about that, I'll vote up because I also really want to know the answer :)

Comment: @KingKing well I got it working, still unsure why or how though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure of the exact issue that was causing this.  I think it has to do with something like setting the datacontext in my main window, but then setting it to something else inside the control ( a different view model ).

Somehow this was confusing the binding system or something??

Anyway, to get this working I added the Source section to the binding, so my Main Window xaml would look something like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel Key="MainWindowViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<!-- Later on -->
<controls:TreeViewControl SelectedFolder={Binding MySelectedFolder, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}" />
```

If anyone can explain to me why I have to explicitly tell the binding the source, i will gladly mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: +1 as for what I promised, it is so strange because this XAML code in fact is very similar to the code behind as you did before with `this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()`. It's stranger that you don't even need `Mode=TwoWay`?

Comment: BTW, I think your issue might be the `DataContext` is not inherited/cascaded down correctly from the `Window` to your `TreeViewControl` as **emedbo** pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has everything to do with DataContext. 
In order to fix this, you need to do the following:

In TreeViewControl.xaml: 
Apply an x:Name attribute in the UserControl declaration, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TreeViewControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="thisUserControl">
```

Refer ElementName in your binding in order to bind to this property:

```
<TreeView SelectedItem={Binding ElementName=thisUserControl, Path=SelectedFolder} />
```

This way you're not messing up the DataContext flow from the ViewModel, and you'll be able to bind to your super tree view.

Comment: Yours is the only post I've found which mentions x:Name, including the official Microsoft examples so a big thank you. I was trying to use DependencyProperty on a DataGrid that lives inside a UserControl.